# Comparing immutable data types

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, collections, immutability

Is there a commonly accepted way of how to compare immutable objects that might contain long lists of values?

So far, my interfaces are as follows:

```
interface Formula : IEquatable<Formula> {
   IList<Symbol> Symbols {get;}
}

interface Symbol : IEquatable<Symbol> {
   String Value {get;}
}
```

Here, the immutable datatype `Formula` represents a sequence of `Symbol`'s. So in a formula:

```
x -> y
```

symbols would be `x`,`->`,`y`.

I want to compare two Formulas based on their content (e.g. a list of symbols). So `new Formula(symbols)` would equal `new Formula(symbols)` for some arbitrary list of symbols.

However, I don't want to iteratively compare two lists all the time.

I was thinking, in implementation, of creating some kind of calculated value during the initialization of the `Formula` - and using that for comparison. However, that will require me to add a method of some sort to my interface. What would I call that method?

I am not sure if it is appropriate to use hash code for this, as it seems to be limited to integers.

Any help appreciated - and if something is not clear I will revise my question.
Thank you!

Comment: It is not so much the comparison of objects but more about how one formula can be identical to another one. Before comparing you need to normalize and simplify the formula to one common form. After that you can compare the elements one by one until you have nothing to compare (equal) or you have detected inequality.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not interested in "how" to compare formulas. Imagine they are already normalized. And comparing "one by one" is exactly what I am asking if I can avoid.

Comment: Is your equality comparison supposed to return `true` when one formula is `a + b` and the other is `b + a`?

Comment: @phoog Nope. Perhaps I should have abstracted my question away from formulas. I'ts mostly a general practice type of question - about lists and comparisons by value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could definitely use a hash code for this. Don't forget that a hash code doesn't have to be *unique* - it just helps if it doesn't give collisions (two unequal sequences with the same hash code) terribly often. (At least, try to come up with an approach which avoids equal hash codes for *obvious* situations.)

So you could compute the hash code *once* on construction (by combining the hash codes of each symbol in turn), then return that from `GetHashCode` without recomputing it each time. That would mean that you'd only ever need to compare sequences with equal hash codes - which would rarely happen for non-equal sequences.

Comment: Perhaps and true for the most part - but it is possible that two different sequences might return the same hashcode. The number of possibilities in a Formula FAR exceed the storage capacity of an int. This might result in subtle, non-reproducible errors at some point in the future.

Comment: Interesting... so if hash codes are equal I simply go on and compare them? That's cool - I never thought of that approach.

Comment: @drozzy: Yes, exactly. And for things like `HashSet<T>`, this would be done automatically before you even got to `Equals`.

Comment: @ananthonline: Did you read my second sentence? "Don't forget that a hash code doesn't have to be unique" - you *always* need to assume that there can be hash collisions. They can still narrow down the field incredibly quickly.

Comment: This means that 99.999% of calls to Equals will be O(1) if the objects are actually *not* equal.  If they really are equal, it will be O(n) and you will need to iterate through every single item in the collection.  There is *no* way around that fact.  You can only ever optimize the cases where Equals returns false.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, exactly. (While something like `HashSet<T>` will check the hash codes first, it makes sense to check it in Equals too, just in case it *is* called manually.)

Comment: My bad. :) I was once trying to use this with the hashcode of string-ized expression trees and shot myself in the foot.

Comment: @JonSkeet so there is no feature to iterate just the objects in that hash bucket?

Comment: @Blam: In what? You're assuming some sort of collection which we haven't been told about...

Comment: If you utilized a enum to store the essential codes and their masking equality at the integer level and then created an Extension Method which utilized a HashTable you would be able to iterate the items in the hash bucket as well as coalesce them from the string representation without storing a separate hash for each instance.  See my answer below. In short I am saying that since there are only certain characters which can vary the output of the equation value such as variables or digits then all signs must have unique HashCodes to give you the ability to cache the other symbols in a hash....

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks when Servy said collection he meant collection of symbols.  I was thinking collection of formulas and you are correct that is not in the question.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to compare all of the elements.  You can't use hash code or a similar approach, because the set of possible formulas is infinite, while the set of possible hash codes is finite.

As Jon Skeet notes, you could use hash codes to *reduce* the need to compare formulas element-by-element, but you cannot *eliminate* the need.  When two formulas have unequal hash codes, you know the formulas are unequal, but when they have equal hash codes, you will need to do an element-by-element comparison to see whether they are equal.

Comment: If the lists *were* infinite, how would you expect to compare them anyway? If they were infinite but equal, you'd have to keep going forever.

Comment: @JonSkeet Strings have finite length, but there is an infinite number of possible strings.

Comment: @drozzy I don't mean that a single formula could be infinite, rather, that there is an infinite number of possible formulas.

Comment: @phoog: Your claim that you "can't use hash code" suggests missing the point of hash codes. No-one ever said that they would *eliminate* the need for element-by-element comparisons.

Comment: No there is not a an infinite number of possible strings.  Unicode has a set number of chars x and string has a maximum size y.  The number of combinations would be x to the y factorial - or something like that.

Comment: @JonSkeet I read "I was thinking, in implementation, of creating some kind of calculated value during the initialization of the Formula - and using that for comparison" as implying the use of hash-code comparison *instead of* element-by-element comparison, not to *supplement* element-by-element comparison.  Perhaps that reading was incorrect, but I see nothing in the question that unambiguously contradicts it.

Comment: @phoog: I certainly didn't read it that way - but the question *does* say: "I don't want to iteratively compare two lists all the time" - and that's what a hash code will do. It means you only need to iteratively compare two lists *some* of the time.

Comment: @Blam Yes, you are correct as far as the .NET string is concerned, but more generally, the concept of "string" does not have a finite length nor a finite set of values.

Comment: @JonSkeet point taken -- I saw "don't want to ... all of the time" as an imprecise way of expressing "I never want to ...", which may well have been incorrect.

Comment: Or you can just ensure your hashCode algorithm does not produce collisions... :P

Comment: @Jay That is not possible, unless you can ensure that the set of values being hashed is smaller than the set of available hash values.  Consider .NET hash code (32 bits) for a 64-bit integer.  There are 2^64 possible input values and 2^32 possible output values.  If the distribution is perfect, there will be over 4 billion collisions for each hash code.

Comment: Incorrect... you only need to normalize to 32bits.... so I can have infinite representations with 2^32 normalized output values. From the master 2^32 normalized output values I have an infinite set with distinct values in an ExtendedHashCode which has more than 2^64 possible outputs which removes this limit at that level. This restriction is only in place because of the datatype of the CLR GetHashCode. With this notion I have have a collision and still revert to the ExtendedHashCode to determine anything without performing further operations unless warranted. +1

Comment: @Jay: having 2^64 bits in your extended hash code will not eliminate collisions. In fact, if you consider only 14-character strings containing only the characters 'A' to 'Z', you are guaranteed to have collisions, because there are more than 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 such strings.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that is not all you need to do...

`a+b = (a+b)`

would result in false with your approach.

I believe you have to construct AST (abstract syntax trees) for the expressions on both sides and then compare the expressions.  The AST would do away the parenthesis since they are expressed as hierarchies in the AST.

Comment: Based on the OP's comments on my answer he may not care about this but I do agree!

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda like the other answer for overriding GetHashCode but I have a different approach....
Since the formula appears to have a string representation....

Can't you override GetHashCode and in the override do a

```
foreach(char c in ToString().ToCharArray()){

int hashCode |= c;

}
```

The result of this would yield a 4 byte code which was a packed representation of the symbols in the equation...

This could be taken further if each symbol has specific OpCode which could be looked up in a HashTable.

I would build the HashTable up with alias's of each OpCode so each Symbol would not have to declare a property OpCode.

I would then make an Extension ToOpCode on the Symbol class which did the look-up in the HashTable described above.

I would then utilize the Extension method in the GetHashCode such as

Formula....

```
public override int GetHashCode(){

    foreach(Symbol c in Symbols){

       int hashCode |= c.ToOpCode();

    }

}
```

Symbol....

```
public override int GetHashCode(){
    retuurn Extensions.ToOpCode(this);

}
```

This implementation would yield the same hash for a + b and b + a which is very important per your question...

Additionally if you specified the OpCode in correct succession you would technically be able to compare equations in the form of:

`(a) + (b)` == `(a+b)`

This would be achieved by ensuring the Parenthesis OpCodes were given a value in the HashCode in a different place than the numbers...

E.g. If you have 4 bytes (an integer) the scope depth could be kept in the first byte, the index to the previous or next equation / symbol in the stack would be next and the next two bytes would be reserved for sign data and the value / continuations or number of variables in the equation (exclusive).

This allows you to tell certain things such as how many nesting levels etc so you can essentially override Equals as well to ensure you can differentiate between `a + b` and `b + a` and `((a) + (b))` if required.

For instance you may want to know if the equation is exactly the same with a certain method but in another you may want to know if the equations are doing the same thing but not written the same exact way.

This would also allow you to determine equality in different ways such as checking if the scope depths match and if there are exactly the same amount of steps in the equation rather than just assuming so based on the hash code..

e.g. you could then shift as follows to determine things such as :

hash << 8 would be the dept of parens
hash << 16 would be the previous or next equation pointer for the stack
hash << 24 would be the sign or code value continuation or number of variables in the equation (exclusive)

you could also just do hash == anotherHash but this way gives you much more flexibility with literally no overhead.

If you need more room in the Hash then create a new Method GetExtendedHashCode which returns long and then shift / downcast or reformat the ExtendedHashCode in GetHashCode to match the int format required by the CLR.

You also have the benefit of the symbols being able to represent variables and values in this way by leaving them as they are on the stack and using them just like the CLR.

Comment: Obviously the algorithm OpCode for chars would be something like:

if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) return c.GetHashCode() else { /*Determine equality and position in hash via shifting inter alia*/ }

Comment: Um... thanks, but I really don't want `a+b` to be the same as `b+a`. Perhaps I  used a bad example, but think of it more as `a->b` and `b->a` - which are different. You approach is interesting though.

Comment: Since you example was not clear  and based on your reply my answer very well may not apply... however it still is better than what was suggested as the given answers neglected to cache the value/hashcode of signs which do not change the equation such as (, ), or = and also required you to maintain their value separately...  With the given example the hashCode not only is unique but tells you things about the equation in advance and allows you to mix and match equality when ever you would like and which ever way while maintaining efficiency over the others.

Comment: Your comment is baseless.... You could abstract the type limitations away with many techniques... once of such techniques is to use a larger hashCode as I have indicated.... last but not least the amount of formulas is not relevant with this implementation as the code depends on the symbols contained their-in and furthermore duplicate symbols will not effect the masked value on the entire value. If you had a requirement to stay within int limited You could always utilize a OpCode.From(Guid) where you allowed a Guid to represent a known qualified formula...

Comment: You would then mask down the HashCode further depending on the Guid or refer to the HashCode of the existing Formula | ExtendedHashCode << 32 ....

Comment: I can read can you compute (and name call)?  Int32 based HashSets are pretty much accepted as a best practice.   Where does the overhead of avoiding a collision exceeds the cost of dealing with a collision?  Given the nature of the problem even Int32 is big for the avoid versus deal.

Comment: A bigger hashCode will save memory?  You lost me at baseless.

Comment: Quite obviously when compared to doing the in depth comparison on collision per time as Skeeter suggested. BLAM!

Comment: The technique `int hashCode |= c` will guarantee that two bytes of the hash code are always zero.  In addition, consider this: "A$" gives the same hash code as "D!": `"A$"` is `{ 65, 36 }` and `"D!"` is `{ 68, 33 }`; both sets of values yield 101 when combined with bitwise or.  You might get better results with the xor operator (`^`).

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to call `ToCharArray` to iterate the characters in a string; `System.String` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: Good call but I was being explicit on the chance that his namespace changed the ToString semantic :P

Comment: @phoog, In those cases you could also perform a salt based on the symbol... e.g. if the symbol value was negative for A and then you would know so based on the bits. Same for odd numbers. In the ExtendedHashCode generation I imagine this would be less of a problem as you would be doing something like `bytes raw[index] = value << raw[index++]` to shift the bits by the value of the symbol at the index as you prepared the hash... you would also be able to do it in a for loop et al. I do agree about the ^ operator I just feel that it should be used intelligently and not just for the reason stated

Comment: For instance the collision would possibly only take me to 1 other binary operation from which I would be able to return a definitive equals to or not without per element inspection.

Comment: @Jay don't get hung up on my example.  My point is this:  For large strings, the probability that each bit is set in at least one character is high.  For *all* such strings, the hash code would be -1: all bits set.

Comment: If the hashCode had the sign bit I would shift it or use it as a continuation :p

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise against implementing `IEquatable<T>` for any non-sealed type `T`.  The only safe way to implement `IEquatable<T>.Equals` on an unsealed type is generally to call the virtual method `Object.Equals`.  Otherwise, there is a possibility that a class whose parent class implements `IEquatable<T>` for one or more types `T` will override `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` without re-implementing all of its `IEquatable<T>` interfaces; any such interfaces that aren't re-implemented will thus be broken.

Secondly, if while comparing the lists in two `Formula` instances, one finds a pair of corresponding `Symbol` references that are equivalent but refer to distinct instances, it may be helpful to call `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()` on each instance.  If one compares larger than the other, replace the reference with the larger `RunTimeHelpers.GetHashCode()` value with the one from the other list.  This will accelerate any future comparisons of those lists.  Further, if one repeatedly compares multiple lists that have the same items, all of the lists will "gravitate" toward having the same `Symbol` instances.

Finally, if one finds that the lists are equal, and if the lists are supposed to be "semantically" immutable, one can use the same `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()` trick to pick a `List` instance.  This will then expedite future comparisons.